# Why does my Kendo Chart not show any data but the series are being rendered in the legen

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

I am working with a Kendo Chart using the MVC wrappers which I need to add series to at runtime based on data in my Model

I have verified that my model does contain valid data when the chart is about to be rendered

The view's model is a chart widget object which contains a series list

This is simply a list of chart series

**Budget Chart Widget**

```
namespace STC.Widgets.Budgeting
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Budget;
    using Extensions;
    using Helpers;

    public class BudgetChartWidget 
    {
        public BudgetChartWidget()
        {
            SeriesList = new List<IBudgetChartSeries>();
        }

        public List<IBudgetChartSeries> SeriesList { get; set; }
        public string ChartTitle { get; set; }
    }
}

**Budget Chart Series**

namespace STC.Widgets.Data.Budgeting
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class BudgetChartSeries : IBudgetChartSeries
    {
        public BudgetChartSeries(string seriesName)
        {
            Values = new List<IChartValue>();
            SeriesName = seriesName;
        }

        public string SeriesName { get; set; }

        public List<IChartValue> Values { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Each chart series then contains values

**IChartValue**

```
namespace STC.Widgets.Data.Budgeting
{
    using System;

    public interface IChartValue
    {
        string DisplayValue { get; set; }
        DateTime Period { get; set;  }
        double? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Partial View for chart**

```
@using STC.Widgets.Data.Budgeting
@model STC.Widgets.Budgeting.BudgetChartWidget

<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model.SeriesList)
          .Theme((string) ViewBag.ThemeName)
          .Name("BudgetViewer" + 1)          
          .Series(series =>
          {
              foreach (var item in Model.SeriesList)
              {
                  series.Column(item.Values).Field("Value").CategoryField("DisplayValue").Name(item.SeriesName);                                    
              }
          })
          .Legend(legend => legend.Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom).Visible(true)) 
          .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
              .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
              .NarrowRange(true)
              .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:N0}"))
              .Line(line => line.Visible(true))
              .Crosshair(crosshair => crosshair.Visible(true)
                  .Tooltip(t => t.Visible(true)))
          )
          .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
              .Labels(labels => labels.Rotation(-90))
              .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
              .Crosshair(crosshair => crosshair.Visible(true)
                  .Tooltip(t => t.Visible(true)))
          )
          .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Format("{0:N0}").Shared(true)))
</div>
```

When I run this the series are shown in the bottom legend but no data shows in the graph

I have checked and there are no Javascript errors

When I use Internet Explorer to view the source of the chart I can see that the data is there

I cant see anything wrong with the way I have created each series, I have even tried varying ways of passing the parameters.

The only one that is relevant to my situation is the one I am using

Can anyone see if I have missed something really obvious please?

Paul

Comment: did you find anything for this?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue, in my case the chart was not shown initially but when I clicked on the legend the chart was shown as expected. After inspecting it seems that the chart was not resizing correctly initially.

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
    @(Html.Kendo().Chart(...)
    .....
</div>
```

`$(document).ready(function () {kendo.resize($(".chart-wrapper"));});` seem to fix this.